# Audio through BLE is possible?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming

I have custom hardware that sends audio using BT and whould like to move on BLE.

So I've developed a GATT server app and a client; setted MTU to 380 and I'm trying to send 8kHz 16bit PCM from one device to another. Results are terrible... and I'm just trying half-duplex while I need a full-duplex communication.

Is possible to achieve this goal?
(to implement full-duplex I can introduce aLaw compression and halve the throughput).

This is the producer, every 20msecs reads 320bytes from audiorecord (8kHz 16bit are 16bytes per millisecond):

```
Runnable audioRecordTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] buff = new byte[micBufferSize];
            audioRecorder.read(buff, 0, micBufferSize);
            snapOnSendAudio(buff);
        } finally {
            audioHandler.postDelayed(audioRecordTask, audioRecordInterval);
        }
    }
};

private void startAudioRecording() {
    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
            .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                    .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                    .setSampleRate(8000)
                    .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                    .build())
            .setBufferSizeInBytes(4096)
            .build();

    if (audioRecorder != null) {
        updateLog("Startin audio recording");
        audioRecorder.startRecording();
        audioRecordTask.run();
    } else {
        updateLog("Audio Record error");
    }
}
```

GATT server informs the client through notification.

Everytime the client is notified the data is passed to an AudioTrack

```
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final String header = "onCharacteristicChanged ";

        if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(SnapOnDataProfile.DATA_CHANNEL)) {
            updateLog(header + "DATA_CHANNEL ");

            updateConsole(characteristic.getStringValue(0));
        } else if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(SnapOnAudioProfile.AUDIO_CHANNEL)) {
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            //updateLog(header + "AUDIO_CHANNEL[" + data.length + "] " + data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " ... " + data[data.length - 2] + " " + data[data.length - 1]);
            audioTrack.write(data, 0, data.length);
        } else {
            updateLog(header + "unknown Characteristic");
        }
    }
```

UPDATE
By terrible result I mean that on client side I hear nothing at all or a brief spike (about a third of second of audio followed by half second of nothing); repeatly.
There is a lot of delay and I just noticed that the client receives only the first 50 packets sent.

Comment: Can you please clarify "results are terrible"? And you have posted the same code twice.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the characteristic read callback and detailed the results